# Fade picture in ffmpeg on Android NDK

Tags: android, video, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I used **ffmpeg** methods without any problems. But I want to modify ffmpeg library to add visual effect between switching videos, if it is possible.

Please help me regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add visual effect I would use mlt framework http://www.mltframework.org/twiki/bin/view/MLT/